How to use playwright workers in UI automation
There are many talks around using multiple workers in playwright when automating a web application. I've a requirement where I am trying to use X workers for my UI automation.
The application is designed in such a way there is a login procedure and then there are multiple pages within the app (like Payments, Entity, Agent Bank etc) each of these has its own functionalities. For eg, for Payment page, there are many fields in that screen few mandatory ones and after filling all the mandatory fields the SAVE button is enabled and payment is created. Likewise for other pages as well.
My playwright code is designed in such a way each of these spec files (Payments, Entity, Agent Bank etc) has a test.beforeAll hook where I first navigate to the URL, do the login procedure etc and then there are multiple tests inside test.describe block. I am using a page object model and calling the page objects for each action in the UI (Like clicking a button, selecting a drop down etc).
It works fine when I use a single worker, but it fails with timeout error when I don't provide --worker parameter leaving playwright to decide on the number of workers.
Given the nature of the application is it possible to employ X workers when testing the app? If yes, what kind of changes I must make to the code? Any help in providing me clarity is much appreciated.
My sample code below:
test.describe.serial('Payment Test Set', () => {
  test.use({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
  let page;
  let paymentPage;
  let commonActions;
  let loginPage;
  let fileManager;

test.beforeAll(async ({ browser, baseURL }) => {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  const { LibraryForUploadingFileToPayment } = await import('./paymentFileUploader.mjs');
  page = await browser.newPage();
  paymentPage = new PaymentsPage(page);
  commonActions = new CommonActions(page);
  loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
  fileManager = new LibraryForUploadingFileToPayment();
  await page.goto(configJson.baseURL, { timeout: 20000, waitUntil: 
  'domcontentloaded'});
  console.log("Payments:Navigation to UAT successful");
  console.log('Page loaded in: ' + (Date.now() - startTime) + 'ms');

  await page.click('role=button[name="AGREE & CONTINUE"]');
  await page.fill('#userName', "xxxx");
  await page.fill('#password', "xxxx$");
  await page.click('role=button[name="LOGIN"]');
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);

  await loginPage.loginForPaymentAutoTestClient();
  await commonActions.clickPaymentsLink();
});

test('Click ADD NEW button', async () => {
    await commonActions.clickAddNewButton();
});
test('Select Direction as PAY', async() => {
    await paymentPage.selectDirectionAsPay();
    paymentDetails.direction = "PAY";
});
test('Enter Amount', async() => {
    const randomNumber = paymentPage.generateRandomNumber();
    paymentDetails.amount = randomNumber
    await paymentPage.enterAmount(paymentDetails.amount);
});
test('Payment Details', async () => {
    console.log(paymentDetails);
});
test('More tests', {
});

test.afterAll(async () => {
    await page.context().clearCookies();
    await page.close();
  });

});
My playwright.config.js (I haven't set anything for using multiple workers in config file)
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import path from 'path';
export default defineConfig({
testDir: './tests',
fullyParallel: true,
forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
reporter: [
/* Uncomment the below line before deploying to AWS */
['html', { 
  outputFolder: 'test-results', 
  open: 'never', 
  embed: true,
 }],
   ['line'],
      ['junit', { outputFile: 'reports/results.xml' }],
   ['json', { outputFile: 'reports/results.json' }],
],
use: {
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
  actionTimeout: 15000,
  navigationTimeout: 50000, 
  timeout: 60000,
  trace: 'on-first-retry',
  screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
  headless: true
},

projects: [
{
  name: 'chromium',
  use: { 
    browserName: 'chromium',
    launchOptions: {
      args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
      }
    },
  },
 ]
});

I tried testing this locally using this command:
npx playwright test ./tests/AgentBankPage ./tests/Payments ./tests/Entity  --headed -- 
reporter=html

As I mentioned above some of the test suites are passing and some are failing with timeout from test.beforeAll hook when playwright employs multiple workers.
I works fine if I hardcode the workers as 1.

First off you have the fullyParallel flag set to true in your config file.  That will attempt to run all test cases across all of your spec files in parallel.  If you want your test cases inside of your spec files to run sequentially then set that to false.
For the login in I would use a global.setup.ts file and get an auth state and then use that for every test case thus bypassing having to log in for every test.
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown
As to your:
workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
Set that to 1:
workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : 1

Also, I'd investigate fixtures as that will make instantiating your page objects so much easier.

Thank you. Do you have an example of global.setup.ts to get an auth state? I have no idea how to do that. Thanks

This is a great video series on Playwright. It's the series that I used to teach myself https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTIxEZng-rc&list=PLXgRgGX8-5UVm9yioRY329rfcfy3MusiY

Here is the specific video on auth states - it's a great one. He takes you through it step by step:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJL6uV7z-8I&list=PLXgRgGX8-5UVm9yioRY329rfcfy3MusiY&index=21
